# Confusion present perfect and simple past

Tags: grammar

I have an argument with my girlfriend about this sentence :

"I have not drunk enough water today"

But I would rather say :

"I have not drank enough water today"

What do you think? We're struggling with a grammar book and can't find the answer

Comment: In particular, see the first section of the duplicate target. Consult a [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com) to help you figure out which form is *drank* and which *drunk*.

Comment: Stick with "drunk".

Comment: Makou - I'm a native & I couldn't tell you ***why*** it's 'drunk' but it is. Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tense of your sentence is **present perfect** and you have to use `have + past participle of the verb "drink"`. The simple past of "drink" is **drank** and the past participle is **drunk**, so the correct form of your sentence will be:

> I have not **drunk** enough water today